# How to Partition records by column and assign sequential number to another column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have input records as mentioned below

```
col1    col2
abcde   vfc
abcde   vfc
abcde   vfc
abcde   dfj
abcde   dfj
abcde   wek
dghkl   tyu
dghkl   tyu
dghkl   tyu
```

I want to create col3 with columns contents as mentioned below.

There can be different values for same record in `col1` if record is different then we need to add `1` if all records are same `col3` value has to be `0`.

```
col1    col2    col3
abcde   vfc     0
abcde   vfc     0
abcde   uil     1
abcde   dfj     2
abcde   dfj     2
abcde   wek     3
dghkl   tyu     0
dghkl   tyu     0
dghkl   tyu     0
```

Comment: Did you try using window functions? Is the dataframe ordered by col1 and col2 ?

Comment: I had partitioned the window using incorrect column now i had corrected the partition column . I am getting expected results

Comment: It's expected on Stack Overflow that you summarize your question properly, don't just say "Spark using Scala", that's not a question. You can still edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df=Seq(("abcde","vfc"),("abcde","vfc"),("abcde","vfc"),("abcde","dfj"),
      ("abcde","dfj"),("abcde","wek"),("dghkl","tyu"),("dghkl","tyu"),("dghkl","tyu")).toDF("col1","col2")
    val WinSpec=Window.partitionBy('col1).orderBy('col2)
    df.withColumn("col3",dense_rank().over(WinSpec))
      .withColumn("col3",when('col3===1,0).otherwise('col3-1)).orderBy('col1).show(false)


+-----+----+----+
|col1 |col2|col3|
+-----+----+----+
|abcde|dfj |0   |
|abcde|dfj |0   |
|abcde|vfc |1   |
|abcde|vfc |1   |
|abcde|vfc |1   |
|abcde|wek |2   |
|dghkl|tyu |0   |
|dghkl|tyu |0   |
|dghkl|tyu |0   |
+-----+----+----+
```